# Kafka consumer offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Getting below exception while starting Kafka consumer.

> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException:
> Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions{test-0=29898318}

Kafka version: 9.0.0
Java 7

Answer (score 37):

So you are trying to access offset(`29898318`) in topic(`test`) partition(`0`)  which is not available right now.

There could be two cases for this

1. Your topic partition `0` may not have those many messages
2. Your message at offset `29898318` might have already deleted by retention period

To avoid this you can do one of following:

1. Set `auto.offset.reset` config to either `earliest` or `latest` .
   You can find more info regarding this [here](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#consumerconfigs)
2. You can get `smallest offset` available for a topic partition by
   running following Kafka command line tool

**command:**

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list <broker-ip:9092> --topic <topic-name> --time -2
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks buddy , I try this but not works.  `auto.offset.reset` should be `latest` , ` earliest` or `none`

Comment: try with the `latest`

Comment: Was getting this error while `auto.offset.reset=latest`. Had to configure a new `group.id` to clean Kafka's offset state then the consumer started working.

Comment: @BdEngineer `retention_period` has no relation with `group.id`. Setting a new `group.id` refreshes the meta (at Broker) for the consumer group. Since this is an edge case, there is no _permanent_ (configurable?) solution.

Answer (score 3):

I hit this SO question when running a Kafka Streams state store with a specific changelog topic config:

- `cleanup.policy=compact,delete`
- retention of 4 days

If Kafka Streams still has a snapshot file pointing to an offset that doesn't exist anymore, [the restore consumer is configured to fail](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.1/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsConfig.java#L1056). It doesn't fall back to the earliest offset. This scenario can happen when very few data comes in or when the application is down. In both cases, when there's no commit within the changelog retention period, the snapshot file won't be updated. (This is on partition basis)

Easiest way to resolve this issue is to stop your kafka streams application, remove its local state directory and restart your application.

Comment: Check the ‘state.dir’ config setting of the kafka streams application; https://kafka.apache.org/10/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#state-dir