# Even after setting "auto.offset.reset" to "latest" getting error OffsetOutOfRangeException

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

me using spark-sql-2.4.1 version with Kafka 0.10 v.

While I try to consume data by consumer.
it gives error below even after setting **"auto.offset.reset" to  "latest"**

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetOutOfRangeException: Offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions: {COMPANY_INBOUND-16=168}
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.throwIfOffsetOutOfRange(Fetcher.java:348)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:396)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:999)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:937)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.fetchData(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:470)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.org$apache$spark$sql$kafka010$InternalKafkaConsumer$$fetchRecord(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer$$anonfun$get$1.apply(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer$$anonfun$get$1.apply(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.util.UninterruptibleThread.runUninterruptibly(UninterruptibleThread.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.runUninterruptiblyIfPossible(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:209)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.InternalKafkaConsumer.get(KafkaDataConsumer.scala:234)
```

> where is the issue ? why setting is not working ? How should it be
>   fixed?

**Part 2 :**

```
 .readStream()
                      .format("kafka")
                      .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
                      .option("enable.auto.commit", false)
                      .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 1000)
                      .option("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
                      .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
                      .load();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kafka consumer offsets out of range with no configured reset policy for partitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320643/kafka-consumer-offsets-out-of-range-with-no-configured-reset-policy-for-partitio)

Answer (score 4):

auto.offset.reset is ignored by Spark Structured Streaming, use startingOffsets option instead

> auto.offset.reset: Set the source option startingOffsets to specify where to start instead. Structured Streaming manages which offsets are consumed internally, rather than rely on the kafka Consumer to do it. This will ensure that no data is missed when new topics/partitions are dynamically subscribed. Note that startingOffsets only applies when a new streaming query is started, and that resuming will always pick up from where the query left off.

[Source](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#kafka-specific-configurations)